# Ember Cli Model population

Tags: javascript, ember-data, ember-cli

I am building an application on Ember Cli, this is my first ever Ember Application. I have committed the application on GIT here:
https://github.com/freshdev1/ember-test-project

The problem is that the service, referenced in adapters/payment-type.js is giving a valid response. The response is getting mapped on the model but response contains around 22 objects, where as only last object is getting copied to the model, as it is showing in the Ember Inspector tab of Chrome.

Secondly I cannot show any of the value of properties in the model.

**Model:**

```
// app/models/payment-type.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

var attr = DS.attr;

var paymentTypes = DS.Model.extend({
    name : attr('string'),
    inoutFlag: attr('string'),
    shortCode: attr('string'),
    paymentType: attr('string'),
    bankAccountRequiredFlag: attr('string'),
    depositSlipFlag: attr('string'),
    maccPaymentFlag: attr('string'),
    referenceRequiredFlag: attr('string'),
    confirmationRequiredFlag: attr('string'),
    creditCardRequiredFlag: attr('string'),
    payeeRequiredFlag: attr('string'),
    affectsBankAccountFlag: attr('string'),
    clearanceRequiredFlag: attr('string'),
    paymentRequiredFlag: attr('string'),
    outstandingFlag: attr('string'),
    includeInBankFile: attr('string'),
    defaultDirectPayTypeCode: attr('string'),
    inspecieTransferFlag: attr('string')
});


export default paymentTypes;
```

**Route:**

```
// app/routes/paymentlisttype.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.findAll('paymentType');
    }
});
```

**Template** (snippet):

```
// app/templates/paymenttypelist.js

{{#each payment-type as payType}}
<snip>
<td>{{payType.paymentType}}</td>
<td>{{payType.name}}</td>
<td>{{payType.shortCode}}</td>
<td>{{payType.depositSlipFlag}}</td>
td class="text-center"> {{input disabled="true" type="checkbox" value=payType.includeInBankFile }}</td>
<snip>
```

What I have done?

**- Removed all ambiguous files from model and other folders.** (You may find them still on the GIT, but locally they do not exist.)

Tutorial I followed is the following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLXGKNA4P_g

JSON recieved from server is the following:

```js
{
    "paymentTypes": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "A",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "DISH",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "name": "Dishonour",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "N",
            "inoutFlag": "O",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "B",
            "depositSlipFlag": "N",
            "shortCode": "BD",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "name": "Bank Draft",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "N",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "O",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "N",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "C",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "ADO       ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "N",
            "name": "CEMTEX",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "N",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "I",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "D",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "DDO       ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "Y",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "name": "Direct Deposit Out",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "O",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "N",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "Y",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "E",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "DD        ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "Y",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "name": "Bank Direct Deposit",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "N",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "O",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": null,
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "F",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "DDR       ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "name": "Direct Debit Request",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "N",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "N",
            "inoutFlag": "B",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "N",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "Y",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "I",
            "depositSlipFlag": "N",
            "shortCode": "INTRAN    ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "N",
            "name": "In  Internal Transfer",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "N",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "B",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "Y"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "K",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "ANZBANK   ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "Y",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "name": "ANZ Bank File",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "N",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "O",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "Y"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "M",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "M/ORD     ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "N",
            "name": "Money Order (Australia Post)",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "N",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "I",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "Y"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "N",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "INTERNAL  ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "Y",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "N",
            "name": "Internal Transfer",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "B",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "O",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "OUTTRAN   ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "Y",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "N",
            "name": "Out Internal Transfer",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "N",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "I",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "P",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "GRPC      ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "N",
            "name": "Split Payment Type",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "N",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "I",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "Q",
            "depositSlipFlag": "Q",
            "shortCode": "CHQ       ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "Y",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "N",
            "name": "Cheque",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "B",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "R",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "CHQR      ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "Y",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "name": "Cheque Receipt",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "N",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "N",
            "inoutFlag": "I",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "S",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "CASH      ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "N",
            "name": "Cash - Dollars and Coins",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "N",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "I",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "V",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "REV       ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "N",
            "name": "Reversal Deposit",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "N",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "N",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "I",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "W",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "BPAY      ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "N",
            "name": "BPay Payment",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "N",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "I",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "X",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "CORR      ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "Y",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "name": "New Corro Payment Type",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "B",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": null,
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": "Q",
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "Y",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "CASH      ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "N",
            "name": "Cash - Dollars and Coins",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "N",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "N",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "Y",
            "inoutFlag": "I",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "N",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "Z",
            "depositSlipFlag": "X",
            "shortCode": "DDR_PAY   ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": "N",
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "name": "New DDR Payment",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": "N",
            "referenceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": "N",
            "payeeRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": "N",
            "inoutFlag": "I",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": null,
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "Y",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "j",
            "depositSlipFlag": "Q",
            "shortCode": "dfgdfgg   ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": null,
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": null,
            "name": "gdfgg",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": null,
            "referenceRequiredFlag": null,
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": null,
            "payeeRequiredFlag": null,
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": null,
            "inoutFlag": "O",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": null,
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": "Y",
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "N"
        },
        {
            "id": 0,
            "paymentType": "t",
            "depositSlipFlag": "N",
            "shortCode": "ertert    ",
            "maccPaymentFlag": null,
            "bankAccountRequiredFlag": null,
            "name": "erter",
            "confirmationRequiredFlag": null,
            "referenceRequiredFlag": null,
            "creditCardRequiredFlag": null,
            "payeeRequiredFlag": null,
            "affectsBankAccountFlag": null,
            "inoutFlag": "B",
            "clearanceRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "paymentRequiredFlag": "Y",
            "outstandingFlag": "N",
            "includeInBankFile": null,
            "defaultDirectPayTypeCode": null,
            "inspecieTransferFlag": "Y"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help all code can be seen by visiting the URL above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first glance I see a thing: the JSON payload returned objects with `"id": 0` for all the models.

First of all I don't think that `"id": 0` is valid, you must start from 1 upwards.
Secondly, if you receive multiple object with the same id, the previous object is overridden by the following, so in the end remains only the latest.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out before and corrected it and just when i came to my question to answer it. Found your answer.